# unable to set rowspan attribute of a html table cell using js

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, popup, bootstrap-modal

I have given html(only one row)table with rowspan of 2 and a button. My aim is to show the table in popup window when user clicks the button using javascript.

My problem is I am failing to set the rowspan attribute for table to show in popup window using javascript. I am using for loops and tried setting the rowspan attribute as .rowSpan in the js code. but I am seeing the table differently(attached the screenshot after popup window is shown)

Please check and help me on how to resolve this. Below is the code.

```js
function addTable() {
    var modalbody = document.querySelector('.modal-body');
    if (modalbody.childElementCount <= 1) {
        var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myTableBody");
        var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
        var oldtble = document.getElementById('table1');
        table.border = '1';
        var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
              var tr = document.createElement('TR');
              tr.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
              tr.style.padding = '5px';
              tableBody.appendChild(tr);
              for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                  var td = document.createElement('TD');
                  td.width = '100px';
                  td.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
                  td.style.padding = '5px';
                  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML));
                  tr.appendChild(td);
                }
            }
    }tableDiv.appendChild(table);
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Twitter Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row" rowspan="2">1</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>Bird</td>
        <td>@tweetUrLarry</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Johny</td>
        <td>Bairstow</td>
        <td>@bairstowJ94</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="button1" onclick="addTable();">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myTableBody">
            <h5 class="lead">Make some coding to display that table</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Results:

[image: Before popup]
[image: After popup]

Comment: Which exact element are you trying to span in your js code?

Comment: @a.mola, in results(first screenshot), the first element is rowspan of 2. i want to apply rowspan for that i=1 and j=0th element position(using for loops)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just saw your comment, Then in the one of your loops you just have to check if the indexes are what you need, like so

```
if (modalBody.childElementCount <= 1) {
    ...

    const oldtble = document.querySelector('#table1 tbody');

    ...

    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

        ...

        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            ...

            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldtble.querySelectorAll('tr')[i].cells[j].innerHTML));

            // before the appending to row.
            if (i == 1 && j == 0) td.setAttribute('rowspan', 2);

            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: i tried as you said above but I am not getting the expected result.

for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
   var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tr.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
   tr.style.padding = '5px';
   tableBody.appendChild(tr);
   for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.width = '100px';
    td.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
    td.style.padding = '5px';
    if (i==1 && j==0) {
     td.setAttribute('rowspan', 2);
    }
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML));
    tr.appendChild(td)}

Comment: Sorry,I made a mistake, your column and title put me off. I don’t think you need to set the `rowspan`, I think you need to set the `colspan`. That’s is for the row’s cell to fit more than one column

Comment: thanks again for suggestion. but the problem here is to merge two cells of different rows(rowspan) not of same row(colspan). plse help in how to do rowspan using js?

Comment: Okay, when the JS has finished running, can you show the way the table is through your DevTools

Comment: can you please tell me how i can show here?

Comment: From the image link you posted, I saw that the modal has only one row apart from the header. Which other row do you want it to fill with

Comment: the row with values(johny bairstow @bairstowJ94) is not coming on popup window. The rowspan(merging the cells of html vertically) is applied to first element which has value 1. and for that element we have two subrows. by above code, i am getting first sub row (values are larry bird @tweetUrLarry) but not second sub row(johny bairstow @bairstowJ94).

Please check and comment

Comment: Here’s your problem, in your first for loop the condition is wrong... `i < 2` will always stop at 1. That’s why you’re not getting 2 rows in the modal table. The condition is meant to be `i <= 2`

Comment: that's the complexity involved here.. if I use i<=2, then js is searching for second-row but the table only has one row apart from the header row. so for i=0, js will print the header row and for i=1 js will print the only row present in the table. if I give i<=2, then it is throwing an error as second-row doesn't exist in my table.

The two sub rows(first: larry bird and second: Johny Bairstow) are part of one single row which is tagged to the first cell(value is 1).

Comment: Please try what I've edited in my answer, I changed the oldtable selector so you'll get only the rows in the body

Comment: sir, no it is not working... i modifed the code according to you but now i am not at all seeing the table itself on popup. and in devtools console tab, i am seeing error at this line(td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldtble.querySelectorAll('tr')[i].cells[j].innerHTML));) that uncaught exception error cant read the property innerHTML of undefined